# batch file exclude some dir from search

Tags: command-line, batch, batch-file

I'm running this small example script:

getConfs.bat myconfig.conf

getConfs.bat looks like this:

```
set home_dir=C:\Program Files\myApp
set dontSearchLoc="%home_dir%\confs\users" "%home_dir%\confs\system\home"    
call :getFiles

:getFiles
for /R "%home_dir%"\confs\ %%f IN (%~1) do (
        FOR %%a IN (%dontSearchLoc%) DO (
         echo "%%f"
         echo "%%a\%%~nxf"
         If %%f=="%%a\%%~nxf" (
          echo Yes
         ) else (
            echo No>> NUL 2>&1 )
        )
)
exit /B
```

The problem with this is that the strings never match, even though the file "myconfig.conf" DOES exist in some of those locations.

I'm getting these returns:

```
"C:\Program Files\myApp\confs\tests\myconfig.conf"
```

and

```
""C:\Program Files\myApp\confs\tests"\myconfig.conf"
```

Obviously from a literal string comparison, they don't match. But logically from a path perspective they do. I feel like im just going about this the wrong way or im not understanding the quotes and how to properly escape them.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: At first, change `%%a` to `%%~a`; then *always* quote whole paths but not its elements, so avoid `"%home_dir%"\confs` and use `"%home_dir%\confs"` instead...